# API Yahoo India Maps

Tags: yahoo-api, yahoo-maps

Yahoo has separate map for India ( which has more details than the regular maps.yahoo.com) at http://in.maps.yahoo.com/ . But when I use the API it goes to default map. How do I get API access to YMaps India?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about yahoo, but there is another mapping website that provides an API for India.

http://biz.mapmyindia.com/APIs.html